# Website works locally, but not on a web hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have somehow made my website work locally. But whenever I try to upload it to either netlify or heroku I keep getting errors or it simply refuses to load. It's a react app that uses axios to make API calls for crypto prices. Additionally, in the Public folder of the same website ( where index.html for react app is ) I have a webscraping vanilla JS app that pulls stock prices from yahoo.finance and stores in into a CSV ( excel file ). Then I have an async function to display that data into HTML from an excel file.

In order to make the app display data I have to change the start script in package.json to

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
"server": "node public/index.js",
"build": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run start\"",
```

I'm using concurrently because I need to start the react server "npm start" and start the node.js server "node index.js" together so one can display data and one can pull data.

If I do "npm run build" - it works flawlessly.. if I upload the website to netlify or heroku - it' s errors on errors.. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've been battling with it for quite a while :(

**UPDATE**

Heroku - it starts the node.js server, but doesn't deploy the website (I can see it update the stock prices in my terminal, but error when I check the URL).. it also throws this error

```
-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js
Terminated
/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/2cd3309e34d34b154aac9f665b0eb2d2e86d8b8e/lib/monitor.sh: line 1: kill: (3899) - No such process
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:795:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:807:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at OutputWriter.write (/tmp/build_6f046d26/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/output-writer.js:60:31)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (/tmp/build_6f046d26/node_modules/concurrently/dist/src/concurrently.js:71:77)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/tmp/build_6f046d26/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:205:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
 !     Push failed
```

For Netlify:

1. If I drag n drop, it will upload the website but it fails to load it
2. If I connect it thru github it completely fails to deploy

Here's my GITHUB - maybe someone can check it out on their own..

https://github.com/szumi112/stockpricesapp

Comment: What actual errors are you seeing?

Comment: What are the errors ? Any screenshots ?

Comment: There could be a number of issues that might not even be related to code like node/library versions but the best thing to do is give us the errors to see what we can focus on

Comment: `react-scripts start` generally starts a server. So does, presumably, your npm `server` script. So stop doing that: either start your own server, or have react-scripts start the `create-react-app` server, but don't start two servers at the same time.

Comment: run `react-scripts build` and then deploy the contents of the generated `/dist` folder.